# Mouse Cursor Occasionally Looks Wonky

Tags: windows-7, video, drivers, mouse

My computer has three video cards, six monitors, and (believe it or not) a mouse.

Generally, all six outputs display the correct mouse cursor. Occasionally, the outputs on a random video card will display a vertical series of dots or a 64x64 grid of dots. But when I move the mouse so the cursor switches to another type (i.e. to enter text or resize a window), sometimes it will display correctly. Other times it will display a different series of dots.

If I move the mouse cursor back and forth between outputs of different cards, it changes back to normal after 30 to 50 back-and-forth gestures.

- I've ruled out a defective card, as it's happened on two Radeon X1650s and two Radeon HD4670s.
- I've ruled out the driver as I've used three different versions *and* the Windows generic video driver.

Why does this happen? 
How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the hardware cursor?

Comment: No... I don't see that option in the mouse control panel; where is that?

Comment: +1 for explaining *why* you ruled out certain error sources.

Comment: What IS are you running?  Windows 7?  XP?

Comment: @David: My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: Does this also happen when DWM is disabled?

Comment: I have the same issue with my Radeon 5870 by the way, so it seems like a driver thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the above comment suggestions:

- does this happen when DWM is disabled?

In other words, switching to Aero Basic un-hardware accelerated desktop.

This is *somewhat* endemic to all Radeon cards under some conditions. I have three monitors hooked up to a single Radeon 58xx series card and I've seen it -- but it is extremely rare. And I can't recall seeing it in a while.

Also I [found a video](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32510504/-my-mouse-pointer-becomes-8-dots--heres-the-video.aspx) documenting the Radeon pointer corruption and uploaded it to youtube. Does it look like this?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iP7HMIJkbKk&hd=1

Comment: Yep, that's it.  Interesting it only happens on the screens on one card at a time when the other cards are on the same driver.